# ImportError: from django.conf import DEFAULT_STORAGE_ALIAS, settings

Tags: django

am trying to run my django app on local server and instead am getting this error: ImportError, cannot import name 'DEFAULT_STORAGE_ALIAS' from 'django.conf'

Answer (score 2):

had the same error today. it seems to be due to a malformed django upgrade (4.1.3 => 4.2.7, but the old version wasn't removed).

using `pip install --upgrade django` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem,
so I reinstalled the `Django 4.1` version that I work with.

```
pip uninstall django 
pip install django==4.1
```